# Paypal Checkout - Remove Order Summary on Paypal Login

Tags: magento, paypal

I am integrating magento with paypal express checkout. When my customer select the paypal, they will redirect to paypal page, can I remove Order Summary block on Paypal login page (on left side) ? Or can I change the "Order Summary" words with something like "Reservation Summary" ?

Highly appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to control that. PayPal is the one who hosts, and thus controls, what users see in their checkout process.

What you can control is the landing page they return to to finish the process.

Comment: Thank you. Finally, i use express checkout with review after user logged in.